# Windows does not recognize the VB shell

Tags: windows, vbscript

I work on a Windows 2003 server. When I create a VB script on it like `test.vbs`,  I don’t get the typical VB icon. In place of that I get a different icon.

Also, when I run the test.vbs, Windows shows a "open with" window

Why does Windows not recognizes the VB shell?
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get the "open with" dialog, there is an option to choose an arbitrary program. Use that option and choose either "C:\Windows\system32\cscript.exe" or "C:\Windows\system32\wscript.exe". The former runs the Vbscript in a command line shell (which normally works best), the latter uses a windowed environment (any WScript.echo command goes to a message box), which is typically not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your associations may be off, try to run : `cscript //H:cscript or //H:wscript`.